# System.Threading.Thread Timer to run on certain date

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am working on a C# project and I am trying to trigger an event on the 1st of every month.

I have the following code so far

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(19, 17, 00);

DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan timeToGo = timeSpan- current.TimeOfDay;
ScheduledTaskExec scheduledTaskExec = new ScheduledTaskExec();

Timer timer = new Timer(x =>
{
    scheduledTaskExec.executeTask();
}, null, timeToGo, TimeSpan.Zero);
```

I'm not sure how I can extend this to make it work so that it will fire the timer on the 1st of each month at a particular time.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why do you need to schedule it via C#?  There are a host of scheduling utilities, including Windows Scheduler, which can handle "Run this .exe on the 1st of every month at XYZ time"

Comment: It needs to be windows and Mono under Linux compatible, should have mentioned that in the post sorry. I don't want to have to have a separate executable that does the work for the schedule

Comment: For something like scheduling when an executable you might want to take the hit and create OS specific solutions. Adding something to an OS's scheduler is a 5 min. job.

Comment: To continue on what Adam said, even if you did this via code you would need OS specific solutions to make sure your program is always running in the background to handle starting the task (Services on Windows and I don't know what on Linux)

Comment: The executable will be running permanently 24/7. I just need too execute a function at a certain time

Answer (score 1):

Timers are not designed for long periods, you need to use external tools (that are OS specific and are usually integrated in to the OS) that can start your process up on the scheduled date.

Most OS's have API's you can hook in to in your code that will let you create those tasks programmaticly. [Here is a managed wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) that will let you create and manage windows scheduled tasks via code. You will need to do your own research how to create similar scheduled tasks on Linux via code.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at [Quartz .Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). It's a .Net port of Quartz for Java. I've used it in the past for scheduling. You can use it in a Windows service to create an event which will be triggered on the first of every month.

Answer (score 0):

Would DateTime.Subtract work, to get the timespan between a future date and the last time it ran?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae6246z1(v=vs.110).aspx